# JSON normalize with pandas - list indices need to be int

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am working on a large JSON which I'd like to convert to csv for further analysis.
As I am building the table using json_normalize, it get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Users/Home/Downloads/JSONtoCSV/easybill.py", line 30, in 
>       "status", "text", "text_prefix", "title", "type", "use_shipping_address", "vat_option"
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/normalize.py", line 248, in json_normalize
>       _recursive_extract(data, record_path, {}, level=0)
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/normalize.py", line 235, in _recursive_extract
>       meta_val = _pull_field(obj, val[level:])
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/normalize.py", line 169, in _pull_field
>       result = result[field]
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

In the first step, I did many tests with smaller / more reduced JSON for code verification. Now, as I assembled everything for the complete JSON, I got this error message.

How can I fix this? I am trying to achieve a normalization with pandas like shown here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#normalization

This is the code I have so far. Thank you for your help!

Edit: This is the JSON source: https://pastebin.com/muGBPWv8

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas
import json
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

# Paths
json_file_path = "/Users/Home/Downloads/JSONtoCSV/JSON-Files/Seite0.json"
csv_file_path = "/Users/Home/Downloads/JSONtoCSV/CSV-files/Seite0.csv"
node = "items"

# JSON file open, no pagination information
with open(json_file_path) as f:
    rawjson = json.load(f)
data = rawjson[node]

# remove "number" because it causes errors in pandas.
good_data = eval(repr(data).replace("number", "numbr"))

# normalization
norm_data =  json_normalize(good_data, "items", [
["address","city"], ["address","company_name"], ["address","country"], ["address","first_name"], ["address","last_name"], ["address","personal"], ["address","salutation"], ["address","street"], ["address","suffix_1"], ["address","suffix_2"], ["address","title"], ["address","zip_code"], 
"amount", "amount_net", "attachment_ids", "bank_debit_form", "cancel_id", "cash_allowance", "cash_allowance_days", "cash_allowance_text", "contact_id", "contact_label", "contact_text", "created_at", "currency", "customer_id", "discount", "discount_type", "document_date", "due_date", "edited_at", "external_id", "grace_period", "id", "is_archive", "is_draft", "is_replica",
["items","booking_account"], ["items","cost_price_charge"], ["items","cost_price_charge_type"], ["items","cost_price_net"], ["items","cost_price_total"], ["items","description"], ["items","discount"], ["items","discount_type"], ["items","export_cost_1"], ["items","export_cost_2"], ["items","id"], ["items","numbr"], ["items","position"], ["items","position_id"], ["items","quantity"], ["items","quantity_str"], ["items","serial_number"], ["items","serial_number_id"], ["items","single_price_gross"], ["items","single_price_net"], ["items","total_price_gross"], ["items","total_price_net"], ["items","total_vat"], ["items","type"], ["items","unit"], ["items","vat_percent"],
"label_address", "label_address", "login_id", "numbr", "paid_amount", "paid_at", "pdf_pages", "pdf_template", "project_id", "ref_id", "replica_url",
["service_date","type"], ["service_date","date"], ["service_date","date_from"], ["service_date","date_to"], ["service_date","text"], 
"status", "text", "text_prefix", "title", "type", "use_shipping_address", "vat_option"
])

# save to csv
norm_data.to_csv(csv_file_path, sep=";")
```

Answer (score 0):

I see sevaral problems with your code:

1. You have conflicting id's for metadata. For example, you have `'id'` as metadata (level-1 item) and also `'id'` as an element of your `'items'`. This can be resolved by giving third parameter to `json_normalize`, like

   json_normalize(good_data, "items", [...], "meta."
2. `json_normalize` expect that metadata is stored in dictionaries (probably, of dictionaries, recursively), but you have items with values of type `list`, for example `attachment_ids`. It seems that currently `json_normalize` cannot handle them.
3. Also, it seems that `json_normalize` cannot handle empty dicts, like `"label_address": {}`.
4. Finally, you probably don't need line `["items","booking_account"], ["items","cost_price_charge"], ...` in your third (metadata) argument of `json_normalize`, as elements with such paths are already retrieved as your data (i.e. due to the second argument of `json_normalize`).

Taking into account the problems with `json_normalize`, i'd prefer not to use it for your problem but just write down simple imperative code (with loops/list comprehensions) that creates a table (list of lists) from your JSON and then create `pandas` dataframe from that table.

Comment: Hi - thank you for your comment! I used `json_normalize` only because I need a normalization with a flat table as a result like shown here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#normalization
"Rick Scott" is in the final table multiple times - but only once in the source json.
Do you have any tip for me how to reach that?
I'm totally new to python - so it's quite a hustle to get through :(